# My if statement with a negation does not work

Tags: java, if-statement

My code executes properly only when it is not placed within the `if` statement. Why is that happening? I think there has to be something wrong with the condition which is supposed to check if Strings which are coming from JTextFields aren't empty. 
Here is my code which is working without using the `if` statement:

```
user1.name = name1;
user1.password = pass1;
user1.ip = i1;
save(user1);
```

And here is the badly implemented `if` statement:

```
if(!name1.equals("") && !pass1.equals("") && !i1.equals("")) {
        user1.name = name1;
        user1.password = pass1;
        user1.ip = i1;

        save(user1);            
}
```

**Note:** name1, pass1 and i1 are all Strings of pretty basic values. name1 can be Bob, pass1 can be Bob123 and i1 can be 192.168.32.1

Comment: Hard to know without the actual values of those variables in the `if` statement. Try to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if possible.

Comment: what are the values of name1, pass1, i1 ?

Comment: You can easily debug this either with a debugger or by adding print statements to print the 3 variables.

Comment: Which types are name1, pass1 and i1?

Comment: Use `isEmpty()` instead of "" `if((name1 != null && !name1.isEmpty()) && (pass1 != null && !pass1.isEmpty()) && (i1 != null && !i1.isEmpty()) ) {`

Comment: And for the record: the String class has `isEmpty()` , you dont need to compare to "" manually!

Comment: I downvoted because [no MCVE](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/). Please ensure all code relevant to your problem is included in your post. Of particular benefit here would be the values of each of your `String` variables in your failure case.

Comment: name1, pass1 and i1 are all Strings of pretty basic values. name1 can be Bob, pass1 can be Bob123 and i1 can be 192.168.32.1

Comment: Please do not add such information in comments. Read [mcve] and ensure that your *question* contains all relevant information. And your comment doesn't clarify much, btw.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I think what you meant to say: the posted code doesn't have any obvious problems, thus ... if there is an error, it isn't in the code. Thus all the requests for a MCVE.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Sometimes people tend to ignore the first comments in their inbox, and you know, when you just read your comment ... the OP might think, "he everything right here ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Since you are trying to

> check if Strings which are coming from JTextFields aren't empty

check the doc for the [`isEmpty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty()) method and use something like:

```
if((name1 != null && !name1.isEmpty()) && 
   (pass1 != null && !pass1.isEmpty()) && 
   (i1 != null && !i1.isEmpty()) ) {
      //....

}
```

Comment: If the strings come from `JTextField`s, they will not be `null`.

Comment: @MauricePerry On the other hand, the OP is still not showing us what exactly his code is doing. There is a small (but greater than 0) chance that a person who gets that if statement wrong ... also manages to introduce a null somewhere between 3 textfields and a validation method.

Comment: @GhostCat as you said: there is not enough information to answer

Comment: Your solution does not work

Comment: @JohnnieBonnie what does it mean "it doesn't work?" If the code inside the if block is not executed, it means that at least one of the strings are empty. Debug your code and check it.

Answer (score 3):

A distinct non-answer: you are doing the validation in the wrong place!

Your UI elements should only allow you to trigger that save action when the required values are present. Create a user experience that prevents the user from making mistakes. Instead of investing times to discover "oh, the user made a mistake"!

In other words: you should *listen* to status changes on your text fields, and only when **all three** textfields have an non empty content, only then, you *enable* your Save button/menu item! And when one of field turns empty again, you better disable that button/menu item.